# Codechef Soccer League python

Tags: python

```
def league(cases,teams,score=0):
    if(teams>1 and teams<140):
            a=[[0 for i in range(teams)]for j in range(teams)]
            b=[0 for m in range(teams)]
            c=[0 for n in range(teams)]
            for i in range(teams):
                for j in range(teams):
                    a[i][j]=int(input())
                    if(a[i][j]==1):
                        b[i]=b[i]+1
                    elif(a[i][j]==2):
                        c[i]=c[i]+1
                    if (score>b[i]):
                    score=score
                    else:
                    score=b[i]

            for i in range(teams):
                for j in range(teams):
                    if(a[i][j]==2 and b[i]==j and b[i]==score):
                        score=score+1

            for i in range(teams):
                if(b[i]+c[i]<score):
                    print('0')
                else:
                    print('1')
```

works fine on my python 3.5 ide but codechef shows error!!
what to do ? help

Input

The first line contains T (about 20), the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case has the following form.

The first line of the test case contains a number N (1 <= N <= 140), the number of teams in the league.

The i-th line in the next N lines contains N numbers ai1, ai2, ..., ain. The number aij gives the status of the match between the i-th team and the j-th team:

```
aij = 1  i-th team wins,
aij = 0 i-th team loses,
aij = 2 if the match has not taken place yet.
The input data is such that if i!=j, then aij + aji = 1 or aij = aji = 2. Moreover, aii = 0 for all i.
```

Comment: Can you show error from codechef?

Comment: Runtime Error(NZEC) if i mention league(1,3) otherwise Wrong Answer...but this code provides the exact same answer

Comment: Well, that mean 'non zero error code'. So somewhere things are going out of range. Please try except with catching exception, and printout result...